# special relativity question

Tags: special-relativity, velocity

How can I find the velocity of an object given the time elapsed of trip from the frame of reference of the object and the distance from the frame of reference of Earth.

Comment: If s is the distance from the frame of reference of earth, then from the frame of reference of the object, the distance is length contracted $s\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2}$.  If $\tau$ is the elapsed time from the frame of reference of the object, then the velocity of the earth relative to the object v (and vice versa) is the contracted distance divided by the time $\tau$.  You then have an equation that you can use to solve for v.

Answer (score 1):

So you have proper time and proper length. Use rapidity, $\eta$. For proper length $x$ and proper time $\tau$-

$\eta=\sinh^{-1}{(\frac{1}{c}{\frac{dx}{d\tau}})}=\tanh^{-1}{(\frac{1}{c}{\frac{dx}{dt}})}$

From this you can calculate the velocity $\equiv dx/dt$